# MySQL Connector could not process parameters

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying to loop through an array and insert each element into a table.  As far as I can see my syntax is correct and I took this code straight from [Microsoft Azure's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-python).

```
try:
   conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
   print("Connection established")
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with the user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exist")
  else:
    print(err)
else:
  cursor = conn.cursor()
data = ['1','2','3','4','5']


for x in data:
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test (serial) VALUES (%s)",(x))
   print("Inserted",cursor.rowcount,"row(s) of data.")

conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
print("Done.")
```

When I run this is gets to `cursor.execute(...)` and then fails.  Here is the stack trace.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 29, in 
>       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test (serial) VALUES (%s)",("test"))
>     File "C:\Users\AlexJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 248, in execute
>       prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
>     File "C:\Users\AlexJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 538, in prepare_for_mysql
>       raise ValueError("Could not process parameters")
>   ValueError: Could not process parameters

Comment: I'm pretty sure MySQL requires `%s` to be enclosed in single quotes. Additionally, you will then get a binding issue because the string will be unpacked. Change `("test")` to `("test",)`, noting the comma

Comment: Why do you need to trailing comma in the tuple?  When I try to execute a query without it, it fails.  If I add the trailing comma it works.  I don't understand how this has any effect.  When I type the following in the Python interpreter, it looks like they are the same:  `>>> (1, 2) == (1, 2,)
True`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try this:

```
for x in data:
    value = "test"
    query = "INSERT INTO test (serial) VALUES (%s)"
    cursor.execute(query,(value,))
    print("Inserted",cursor.rowcount,"row(s) of data.")
```

Since you are using mysql module, `cursor.execute` requires a sql query and a tuple as parameters

Comment: insertion is a statement  so variable name `query` is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer.  None of the usual sources of reference docs mention this at all.

Comment: Technically `cursor.execute` requires a _sequence_ or mapping as the second argument, so a list would work as well, but it's conventional to use a tuple, and a list of tuples when calling `cursor.executemany`.

Answer (score 0):

Nice answer from @lucas, but maybe this help other, cz i think more cleaner

```
sql = "INSERT INTO your_db (your_table) VALUES (%s)"
val = [("data could be array")]
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, val)
print("Inserted",cursor.rowcount,"row(s) of data.")
cnx.commit()
cnx.close()
```

Cz this is useful for my purpose, to input multiple data.

Answer (score -1):

I'm facing same issue but instead of array, I'm looping through a set and insert each item into mysql db and got this error `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: str(Data_Tokens), it must be of type list, tuple or dict`.

The uniqueTokenSet includes string data type, but as error shows that it must be list, tuple or dict. By converting `item` to list of tuple `[(item)]` work for me.

```
uniqueTokenSet = set()

for item in uniqueTokenSet:
    tokenSql = "insert into tokens(token) values (%s)"
    data = [(item)]
    mycursor.execute(tokenSql, data)

print('data inserted')
mydb.commit()
```