# Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement when executing executemany()

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I'm using the Python3 version of the mysql-connector and I try to use the executemany function.

My code looks like this:

```
database = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='user',
        password='test',
        database='test_database'
    )
cursor = database.cursor()
categories = ['Test1', 'Test 2']
stmt = "INSERT INTO categories (name) VALUES (%s)"
cursor.executemany(stmt, categories)
```

My table has just one column and this is a string column called name.

I tried to use the entries in the list as tuple, I changed the insert statement to this:

```
stmt = "INSERT INTO categories (name) VALUES ('%s')"
```

So I basically added single quotes in the %s placeholder.
I also tried to replace the %s with ? but that also didn't work.

Due to the Python3 formatting conventions the single execute function is working when I use this:

```
stmt = "INSERT INTO categories (name) VALUES ('{}')".format('Test1')
```

Unfortunately the executemany function needs a second argument so I can't use the .format function.

This is my working example with the normal execute function:

```
database = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='user',
            password='test',
            database='test_database'
        )
cursor = database.cursor()
categories = ['Test1', 'Test2']
for category in categories:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO categories (name) VALUES ('{}')".format(category))

database.commit()
```

Edit:

I've read the official [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html). I copy and pasted the code and changed it to my parameters but it still doesn't work.

```
categories = [('Test1'),('Test2'),]
stmt = "INSERT INTO categories (name) VALUES (%s)"
cursor.executemany(stmt, categories)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to rule out the basics:

I see that the `for` loop you pasted in the question ends with a `database.commit()` statement, but the`executemany` block doesn't. Did you omit this in your code or just in the question?  (sorry I am putting this as an answer..can't add comments yet)

Comment: Hey the code didn't even reach the commit because the exception fired beforehand but I finally found the answer

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the solution of this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518722/mysql-connector-could-not-process-parameters?rq=1) I found a solution.

The statement was correct but my data list was wrong.
If you just provide one value you need a comma inside the tuple.

This is the final solution:

```
categories = [('Test1',),('Test2',)]
stmt = "INSERT INTO categories (name) VALUES (%s)"
cursor.executemany(stmt, categories)
```

This is also documented in the MySQL documentation.