# Cannot insert data in mysql-database: 'ValueError: Could not process parameters'

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I have a list like this:

```
prices= ['$22,999', '$7,499', '$33,000', '$6,000', '$34,600', '$8,999', '$6,200', '$7,975']
```

I want to insert this list to database like this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO abc (a) VALUES (%s)"
mycursor.executemany(sql, prices)
```

but I get error, why?

```
 ValueError: Could not process parameters
```

Comment: Can you show your error messages?

Comment: ValueError: Could not process parameters
@Rizquuula

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Connector could not process parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518722/mysql-connector-could-not-process-parameters)

Comment: I think you must transform the prices to an array of tuples of one element.

Comment: You are trying to input string value into SQL, is your SQL column type is string or numeric?

Comment: @Rizquuula it's text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform list to list of tuples :

```
pricesTuples = [(p,) for p in prices]
```