# How find records with specific date using Python and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I have created small project about students registration. I am using Python and MySQL. I want to how find students registered with specific date. I have tried and created the following codes:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry 
import mysql.connector

my_w = tk.Tk()
my_w.geometry("900x650")  # Size of the window 
my_w.title("Tutorial")  # Adding a title
sel=tk.StringVar()
cal=DateEntry(my_w,selectmode='day',textvariable=sel)
cal.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20,pady=30)
def my_upd(*args): # triggered when value of string varaible changes
    if(len(sel.get())>4):
        dt=cal.get_date() # get selected date object from calendar
        dt1=dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") #format for MySQL date column 
        dt2=dt.strftime("%d-%B-%Y") #format to display at label 
        l1.config(text=dt2) # display date at Label
        con =mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",database='tutorial',user="root",password="")
        cur=con.cursor()
        query="SELECT * from students WHERE regisdate=%s"
        r_set=cur.execute(query,dt1) # execute query with data
        for item in trv.get_children(): # delete all previous listings
            trv.delete(item)
        total=0 # to store total sale of the selected date
        for dt in r_set: 
            trv.insert("", 'end',iid=dt[0], text=dt[0],
               values =(dt[0],dt[1],dt[2],dt[3]))
            total=round(total+(dt[2]*dt[3]),2)
        l2.config(text="Total: " + str(total)) # show total value
l1=tk.Label(my_w,font=('Times',22,'bold'),fg='blue')
l1.grid(row=0,column=1)
trv = ttk.Treeview(my_w, selectmode ='browse')
  
trv.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=20,pady=20)
# number of columns
trv["columns"] = ("0", "1", "2","3")
trv['height']  =20
# Defining heading
trv['show'] = 'headings'
  
# width of columns and alignment 
trv.column("0", width = 30, anchor ='c')
trv.column("1", width = 80, anchor ='c')
trv.column("2", width = 80, anchor ='c')
trv.column("3", width = 80, anchor ='c')

  
# Headings  
# respective columns
trv.heading("0", text ="ID")
trv.heading("1", text ="Name")
trv.heading("2", text ="Contact")
trv.heading("3", text ="RegisDate")  

sel.trace('w',my_upd)

l2=tk.Label(my_w,font=('Times',22,'bold'),fg='red')
l2.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='ne',pady=20)

my_w.mainloop()  # Keep the window open
```

When i run the above code, it raises this error:

Exception in Tkinter callback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Siciid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Siciid\Desktop\Tutorial\datewise.py", line 22, in my_upd
    r_set=cur.execute(query,dt1) # execute query with data
  File "C:\Users\Siciid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 257, in execute
    prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
  File "C:\Users\Siciid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 686, in prepare_for_mysql
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: str(2022-07-25), it must be of type list, tuple or dict
```

Please i need your help.

Comment: Read the error message carefully. This is from line `cur.execute(query,dt1)`. So `dt` must be one of the specified types. `cur.execute(query,(dt1,))` will make a [one item tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_tuple_one_item.asp).

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518722/mysql-connector-could-not-process-parameters I second what danblack said.

Comment: Still i did not understand.