SQL paramter must be list, dict or tuple, but the parameter is a list
I am trying to pass a variable called "data" From a class called LoginOrReg in a file called LoginOrReg to another class in another file Called HabitTracker, but i get a programming error
Here is what i believe to be the minimal reproducible code. I have created the variable in the method called "log_user_in"
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector
import customtkinter
import math
from datetime import datetime 
import HabitTracker as HT



#Handles login and registration
class LoginOrReg:

    customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('dark')
    customtkinter.set_default_color_theme('blue')
    

    def __init__(self, db, cursor, login_username, data):
        self.db = mysql.connector.connect(host = '', user = '', password= '', database="")
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
        self.login_username = login_username
        self.data = data
  #provides the login screen where the user is asked for an existing username and password
    def login(self):
        self.login_window = customtkinter.CTk()
        self.login_window.geometry('400x400')
        self.login_username_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.login_window, placeholder_text ='Enter Your Username')
        self.login_username_entry.pack(pady=30)
        self.login_username = self.login_username_entry.get() 
        self.login_password_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.login_window, placeholder_text ='Enter Your Password')
        self.login_password_entry.pack(pady=30)
        self.login_password = self.login_password_entry.get()
        self.log_user_in_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.login_window, text = 'Login', command = self.log_user_in).pack(pady=30)
        self.reg_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.login_window, text = 'Register New User', command = self.reg_user).pack(pady=20)
        self.login_window.mainloop()

    #Logs the user in
    def log_user_in(self):
        self.habit = HT.HabitTracker(main_window=' ', sorting_options= ' ', sort= ' ', login= ' ')
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT username AND password, COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=%s AND password=%s GROUP BY username',(self.login_username_entry.get(), self.login_password_entry.get()))
        self.cursor.fetchall()
        self.row_count = self.cursor.rowcount
        if self.row_count == 1:
            self.cursor.execute('SELECT userID FROM users WHERE username=%s AND password=%s',(self.login_username_entry.get(), self.login_password_entry.get()))
            self.data = self.cursor.fetchone()
            print(self.data)
            self.user_id = self.data[0]
            self.habit.main_menu(LoginOrReg)
        else:
            self.my_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.login_window, text = "User Not Found. Please Try Again.", font=('Helvetica', 10)).pack(pady=10)


login_reg = LoginOrReg(db = " ", cursor=" ", login_username= ' ', data = ' ')
login_reg.login_or_reg(root=" ")


Here is where I try to call the "data" variable in HabitTracker in the method Main_menu.
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector
import customtkinter
import math
from datetime import datetime
import LoginOrReg as LR


class HabitTracker:
    def __init__(self, main_window, sorting_options, sort, login) -> None:
        self.main_window = main_window 
        self.db = mysql.connector.connect(host = '', user = '', password= '', database="")
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
        self.sorting_options = sorting_options
        self.sort = sort 
        self.login = login
        
    def main_menu(self, LR):
        import LoginOrReg as LR
        self.login = LR.LoginOrReg(db=' ', cursor= ' ', login_username=' ', data= ' ')
        self.date = datetime.today()
        self.main_window = customtkinter.CTk()
        self.main_window.geometry('1080x720')
        self.sorting_options = ['Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Highest Streak',]
        self.mylabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.main_window, text='Welcome {}'.format(self.login.login_username), font=('Arial', 40)).pack(pady=5)
        self.sort = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(self.main_window, values= self.sorting_options, command= sort_by.sort_by)
        self.sort.set('Sort By')
        self.sort.pack(pady=10)
        self.create_new_habit_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.main_window, text='Create New Habit', command=create_habit.create_habit, fg_color='green').pack(pady=20)
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT habit_name FROM habit WHERE user_id=%s GROUP BY habit_name', (self.login.data))
        self.habits = self.cursor.fetchall()
        self.j = 0
        for j in self.habits:
            self.habit_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.main_window, text=self.habits[self.j], command=lambda k = self.habits[self.j]: edit_habit.edit_habit(k))
            self.habit_button.pack(pady=10)
            self.j = self.j + 1
        self.main_window.mainloop()

Here is the error I get
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1968, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 554, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Scanes-Kael_9213430_OOFPP_Habit\Scanes-Kael_9213430_OOFPP_Habit_Submission\Kael OOFPP_Phase 2\LoginOrReg.py", line 84, in log_user_in
    self.habit.main_menu(LoginOrReg)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Scanes-Kael_9213430_OOFPP_Habit\Scanes-Kael_9213430_OOFPP_Habit_Submission\Kael OOFPP_Phase 2\HabitTracker.py", line 30, in main_menu
    self.cursor.execute('SELECT habit_name FROM habit WHERE user_id=%s GROUP BY habit_name', (self.login.data))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 526, in execute
    raise ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: str( ), it must be of type list, tuple or dict


This does not look minimal to me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Restart from scratch. Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem."

self.login.data is a string after login_reg = LoginOrReg(db = " ", cursor=" ", login_username= ' ', data = ' ')

Maybe this answer can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/54518905/1839624

This is the offending line of code:
self.cursor.execute('SELECT habit_name FROM habit WHERE user_id=%s GROUP BY habit_name', (self.login.data))

The second parameter, (self.login.data) is indeed not a list, a tuple or a dict - it's self.login.data surrounded by parentheses.
Add a comma after the variable to make it a single-item tuple:
(self.login.data,)
# Here ---------^

